# Will Upgrading to Mavericks Slow My System?

Tags: upgrade, macos, performance

I have a 2010 iMac and I'm considering upgrading to Mavericks. Will I notice any significant decreases in speed? My specs:

[image]

Comment: This question is not a duplicate. Not only is my machine a completely different model than the one posted in the "duplicate question", but I also have completely different specs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that machine should run mavericks fine; its not much more resource intensive than 10.8 is. Is there some specific aspect of performance you are concerned about?

Comment: Thanks for the response! Nope, just concerned about speed in general.

Comment: I would say worst case scenario you would need to upgrade your RAM (or disable some unneeded features). Mavericks is actually more responsive on my system; scrolling used to lag at times under 10.8, but under 10.9 its smooth. I have a feeling this is due to having 16GB RAM and ox x will now pre-render more of the view if you have RAM to spare. you probably don't having only 4GB.